# Touchscreen Issues with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, touchscreen

I recently updated my laptop from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.
While the Touchscreen was OFF in Ubuntu 22.04 even when the system rebooted, it just doesn't go off in Ubuntu 22.04. I tried everything.
`xinput --list` doesn't show touchscreen id anywhere. I also changed the touchscreen from ON to OFF in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf`

Results of `xinput --list` :

[image: xinput --list screenshot]

Comment: `xwayland-touch` is your touchpad.

Comment: That's true. But i am looking for touchscreen and not touchpad

Comment: Try other devices, or switch to X11.

Comment: How?Can you please guide.

Comment: To disable any device run `xinput disable <ID>`. Take the ID from `xinput` output. You can switch to X11 when you login.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem myself on a lenovo yoga 260 running ubuntu 22.04.
on the login screen for your computer select the options wheel in the right hand corner. Select ubuntu on xorg rather than ubuntu. This makes it so that xwayland does not run and you can use the xinput disable [device id] command without any problem.
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-enable-disable-wayland-on-ubuntu-22-04-desktop

Comment: I fixed the touchscreen issue with this:https://www.blackmoreops.com/2016/10/26/disable-touchscreen-linux/